# Brackets SASS compiling same mixin causes redundant output

Tags: css, sass, adobe-brackets

I have use [foundation breakpoints](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/tree/develop/scss/util) mixins. Here's my code

```
.button {
  width : 200px;

  @include breakpoint(medium){ 
    width:100px;
  }
}

.header {
  height: 50px;

  @include breakpoint(medium){
    height: 30px;
  }
}
```

Here is what I get

```
.button {
  width: 200px;
}

@media print,
screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .button {
    width: 100px;
  }
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
}

@media print,
screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .header {
    height: 30px;
  }
}
```

You can see that @media breakpoints call two times. What I wan't result is like this :

```
.button {
  width: 200px;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
}

@media print,
screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .header {
    height: 30px;
  }
  .button {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

How to make output like that in Brackets SASS? I don't want to take more action that like convert with [CSS minifier](https://cssminifier.com/). Thanks